# Unit test - test a method of a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest

I created a unit test file for testing the method **part_firstname_lastname**. I'm using PyCharm. When I run the test_person.py there's no error. The test is a success.

When I run the file in the command line by using  `python test_person.py -v`, the error is :

> from School.person import Personne ModuleNotFoundError: No module
>   named 'School'
>   Blockquote

In the pycharm I don't have any errors, the import is good.

**School** is a package inside that I have the file **person.py**. The file **test_person.py** is in another package named **Unit_Test**

1- How can i solve it ?
2- Must i use Mock for that ?

```
class Person:

def __init__(self, first, last):
    self.__code = 0
    self.__firstname = first
    self.__lastname = last


def __str__(self):
    return self.firstname + ' ' + self.lastname

@property
def firstname(self):
    return self.__firstname

@firstname.setter
def firstname(self, value):
    self.__firstname = value

@property
def lastname(self):
    return self.__lastname

@lastname.setter
def lastname(self, value):
    self.__lastname = value

@staticmethod
def part_firstname_lastname(data):
    """
    This method take a part of the data
    @param : str : data
    :return: str : part of the data entered
    """
    if len(data) > 3:
        return data[0:3].upper()
    return data[0:1].upper()
```

**test_person.py**

```
    import unittest
from School.person import Person


class test_person(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_code_personne(self):

        p1 = Personne('Callier', 'John')
        p1.part_firstname_lastname(p1.firstname)
        self.assertEqual(p1.part_firstname_lastname(p1.firstname), 'CAD')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Pycharm automatically adds content roots and source roots to PYTHONPATH. Add `print(os.environ['PYTHONPATH'].split(os.pathsep))` and compare the results running it directly and from pycharm

Comment: I always have the error

Comment: "I'm using PyCharm. When I run the test_person.py there's no error." ? So no error or always?

Comment: In PyCharm, but in the teminal, i ran python test_personne.py -v. It always give me the same error.

Comment: can you compare `PYTHONPATH` in both environments?

Comment: It gives me two different paths

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188815/discussion-between-qtcho-and-adrian-krupa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way is to update the PYTHONPATH to contain the folder containing the `School` package.

It can be done at different level:

- inside a tool or framework that will actually launch the test (that is the way PyCharm works)
- change the PYTHONPATH environment variable from the command line before executing the test (syntax will depend of the OS and shell)
- change the `sys.path` system list directly from the `test_person.py` file before importing `School` - beware it is a rather intrusive way
- change the `sys.path` system list from a package containing the `test_person.py`. It can be a handy way if you always use a full test package

Comment: I'm using ubuntu